# PHP not seeing curl post

Tags: php, apache, curl, post, https

I wrote a very simple script to just see what a server was sending like this:

```
<?php
$html1 = <<<EOT
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
  <head>
    <meta charset = 'utf-8'>
    <title>TradingView Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <pre>
EOT;

$html2 = <<<EOT
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
EOT;

date_default_timezone_set('America/Phoenix');

$file = date('Y/m/d h:i:sa') . "\n";

$url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http")
       . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

$file .= "\nURL: $url\n\n";
$html = $file;

if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {
  $r = "\$_REQUEST:\n" . var_export($_REQUEST, true) . "\n\n";
  $file .= $r;
  $html .= htmlspecialchars($r);
}

$headers = apache_request_headers();
if (!empty($headers)) {
  $h = "HEADERS:\n" . var_export($headers, true) . "\n\n";
  $file .= $h;
  $html .= htmlspecialchars($h);
}

//   if (!empty($_SERVER)) {
//     $s = "\$_SERVER:\n" . var_export($_SERVER, true) . "\n\n";
//     $file .= $s;
//     $html .= htmlspecialchars($s);
//   }

$file .= str_repeat('-', 40) . "\n";

file_put_contents('./get-post.log', $file, FILE_APPEND);
# echo $html1 . $html . $html2;

?>
```

In the example for what the server sends they had this example:

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' -d '1111111111,data,more-data' -X POST https://www.testtest.com/
```

I thought with `$_REQUEST` I would see all that was sent but I don't see anything and what the script outputs is:

```
2022/03/30 06:15:22pm

URL: https://www.testtest.com/

HEADERS:
array (
  'X-Https' => '1',
  'Connection' => 'close',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip',
  'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8',
  'Content-Length' => '45',
  'User-Agent' => 'Go-http-client/1.1',
  'Host' => 'www.testtest.com',
)
```

I suspect the issue is that they are not sending the data as a proper POST by naming a field and I can't change how the data is being sent because it's not my server.

Does anyone know what I can look at in PHP to see the data being sent? Or perhaps this is an Apache problem as PHP gets its data through Apache and maybe in that format it's just not getting passed through?

You will note that I have displaying of `$_SERVER` commented out because even when it wasn't it didn't give me anything that helped.

Comment: Read the documentation properly, and learn what kind of data does the server sends

Comment: That is an unhelpful comment and I showed the entirety of their useful documentation which is the curl command above which I duplicated and then used to call the code above which produced the result I showed above so I am showing here everything I have access to. I also used their system to call the code above and got the same result so for now I have no reason to believe there is a difference between the curl command above, which they gave as an example, and their system.

Answer (score 1):

Found it. PHP won't fill `$_POST` without named arguments so to get the string the way it's being sent this needs to be used:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('php://input');
```